# How to provide proxy information to Twilio API with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, twilio, twilio-api

It looks like the Twilio API was updated and they no longer have the ability to import `from twilio.rest.resources import Connection` which means that the docs/answers that show you how to set the proxy with the Connection class no longer work.

ie:

```
from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
from twilio.rest.resources.connection import PROXY_TYPE_HTTP

Connection.set_proxy_info(
    "proxy.server",
    3128,
    proxy_type=PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
)`
```

Does not work, since there is no resources class to import from.

**What is the correct method to set the proxy information for the Twilio Python Library using Python 3 and the lastest code from Twilio?**

There is an issue logged on Github regarding this but it doesn't have a concrete solution yet https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/327

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the issue on GitHub says, we have switched from urllib2 to Requests but not quite made available all the options, like proxies, in the default `TwilioHttpClient`. The issue also suggests that you subclass `HttpClient` to add in the proxy yourself.

As far as I can see, you can just copy the majority of the existing [`TwilioHttpClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/http/http_client.py) adding the proxies to the session object. Like so:

```
from requests import Request, Session

from twilio.http import HttpClient, get_cert_file
from twilio.http.response import Response


class ProxiedTwilioHttpClient(HttpClient):
    """
    General purpose HTTP Client for interacting with the Twilio API
    """
    def request(self, method, url, params=None, data=None, headers=None, auth=None, timeout=None,
                allow_redirects=False):

        session = Session()
        session.verify = get_cert_file()
        session.proxies = {
                              "https" : "https://x.x.x.x:yy"
                          }

        request = Request(method.upper(), url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)

        prepped_request = session.prepare_request(request)
        response = session.send(
            prepped_request,
            allow_redirects=allow_redirects,
            timeout=timeout,
        )

        return Response(int(response.status_code), response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note the call to `session.proxies` in the middle of the `request` method

Then, when you instantiate your `Client`, include your new `ProxiedTwilioHttpClient`.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from proxied_twilio_http_client import ProxiedTwilioHttpClient

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token, http_client=ProxiedTwilioHttpClient())
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing this solution, hopefully it saves people some time. I made some minor edits for things I encountered while implementing your code

Comment: NVM edit queue is full... basically, just need to add an import `from requests import Session, Request` and fix the indentation for the return (formatting issue I suspect)

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to make the edits back to my answer. And if it did solve the problem for you, please mark it as correct too.

Comment: .virtualenvs/sms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXX/Messages.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.Verif
iedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa41a55e090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))

Comment: Hi @AdrianMartínez, it looks like you have a question. It is probably best to start a new question on the site rather than post an stack trace in the comments. If you tag the question with "twilio" then I will be able to find it later and help if I can.

Comment: Hello @philnash, thanks for your replay. I started a question. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44351431/7298530

Comment: I'm on twilio 6.9.1, I'm getting a cannot import on `get_cert_file `.

Comment: Yeah, looks like [`get_cert_file` was removed in August](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/commit/d75a66b20a005594ee9c5d2f10f783fb8ba06776). You should be able to form a new `ProxiedTwilioHttpClient` from the current [`TwilioHttpClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/http/http_client.py). Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: Oh thanks, @philnash! I got it working. I basically just replaced what you provided above with the current TwilioHttpClient class and added the proxy line.

Answer (score 4):

@philnash's answer is now out of date, but the good news is that you can get a proxy http-client working with simpler code:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient

proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient()

# assuming your proxy is available via the standard env var https_proxy:
## (this is the case on pythonanywhere)
proxy_client.session.proxies = {'https': os.environ['https_proxy']}

# assumes you've set up your twilio creds as env vars as well
# you can pass these in here alternatively
client = Client(http_client=proxy_client)

# twilio api calls will now work from behind the proxy:
message = client.messages.create(to="...", from_='...', body='...')
```