# Failed to provide proxy info to twilio pythonanywhere

Tags: python, twilio, pythonanywhere

I am trying to use Twilio in pythonanywhere and I know I need a proxy to make it work. My code looks like this:

```
    class ProxiedTwilioHttpClient(HttpClient):
        """
        General purpose HTTP Client for interacting with the Twilio API
        """
        def request(self, method, url, params=None, data=None, headers=None, auth=None, timeout=None,
                    allow_redirects=False):
        session = Session()
        session.verify = get_cert_file()
        session.proxies = {
                              "https" : "https://52.14.161.178:3128"
                          }

        request = Request(method.upper(), url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)

        prepped_request = session.prepare_request(request)
        response = session.send(
            prepped_request,
            allow_redirects=allow_redirects,
            timeout=timeout,
        )

        return Response(int(response.status_code), response.content.decode('utf-8'))

def send_sms(phone, content):
    client = Client(api_key, api_secret, account_sid, http_client=ProxiedTwilioHttpClient())
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=phone,
        from_="+19999999999", #of course I use the correct one
        body=content)
    return(message.sid)
```

But then it returns the following error:

```
.virtualenvs/sms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/‌​adapters.py",
line 502, in send raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXX/Messages.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.Verif iedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa41a55e090>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))
```

I am using the following answer that seems to work for others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43608637/7298530

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying that your code should use a proxy at `https://52.14.161.178:3128`.  That won't work on PythonAnywhere, you need to use the proxy that the service provides.  To find out what address to use for that, start a Bash console and run

```
echo $http_proxy
```

[2018 edit] We now have a specific page on [getting twilio to work with the pythonanywhere proxy](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TwilioBehindTheProxy)

Comment: ok, now it works, it only need to be https.... Thanks, this really saved me, i really need it.